# TCL script debugging

Tags: debugging, tcl

How to debug TCL scripts?

How to use the console, the debugger and the build-in commands?

Comment: As of 2021 google (debug tcl) lead me to https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/What+debugging+tools+are+available+to+a+Tcl+programmer which seems to contain in source debugging techniques from simple things aka printf to high sophisticated internal anlyzing techniques.

Comment: As of 2021 stackoverflow(debug tcl) lead me to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234097/debug-tcl-flow-like-bash (which was exactly I was searching for) while goggle(debug tcl) and goggle(debug tcl set -x) lead me to this page. stackoverflow(debug tcl set -x) lead me to nothing i was looking for. PS: I did not yet evaluate the technique from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234097/debug-tcl-flow-like-bash. Opinionated: It seems to me looking for external debugging tools is rather pointless for tcl, focussing on internal debugging techniques is better.

Answer (score 8):

The best debugger I know of for Tcl is part of [ActiveState's TclDevKit](http://docs.activestate.com/tdk/5.2/); it's non-free, but highly recommended. (There's also a free 21-day trial available.)

Other options are [available](http://wiki.tcl.tk/473). For one thing, Tcl's built-in `trace` command makes it pretty simple to add in your own breakpoints, watchpoints, do single-step tracing, etc. Yet there's something of a lack of proper free integrated tools (precisely because as a community we get on really well with the ActiveState crew). Still, you might find the next code sample useful:

***Trace all command calls:***

```
# overwrite at each invocation of this script; pick somewhere else if you prefer
set _Trace_fd [open "/tmp/tcltrace.tmp" w]
fconfigure $_Trace_fd -buffering line

rename proc _proc
_proc proc {name arglist body} {
    uplevel [list _proc $name $arglist $body]
    uplevel trace add execution $name enterstep {::apply {{name cmd op} {
        puts $::_Trace_fd "$name >> $cmd"
    }}}
}
```

Note, this produces rather a lot of output with typical code...

Answer (score 4):

TCL is a good tool for debugging TCL. have a look at the [trace](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/trace.htm) command. Also [info](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/info.htm) and [winfo](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/winfo.htm) can be useful. if you want something which wraps these up into a more traditional debugger there is a list at http://wiki.tcl.tk/473

Comment: yes, it correct. U r link is very useful. But what i want to ask to that i want to debug step by step, like in .Net visual studio provide some good debugging tool to debug step into. If u have any more idea please share with me..........

Answer (score 3):

The already mentioned list at the tcl'ers wiki is a good resource, and even though the ActiveState TclDevKit debugger is the best available (and also the one used by the Eclipse based Tcl IDE), there are a few other options.

One might be RamDebugger: http://www.compassis.com/ramdebugger/Intro