# Debug tcl flow - like bash -

Tags: bash, debugging, tcl

I just wondering if there is something like `set -x` as it is present in Bash forTCL which allows me to follow the flow of my script and then help me to debug it.

Answer (score 4):

Simple:

```
trace add execution source enterstep {apply {{cmd op} {puts "+ $cmd"}}}
source yourfile.tcl
```

Comment: what about if I want trace EVERYTHING ?

Comment: **everything** in that file is traced.

Comment: Until the `source` returns anyway…